# How to customize sp 2010 "my site" navigation links and control audiences of this links?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, mysite

i have SharePoint 2010 portal with many users and i configured "my site" , i created some publish pages and by default the pages links appear in "my site" navigation bar ,i want specific users(SharePoint group) only shows this links and other users don't show it

i made the following,

i have create site from template personalization site and then add links as following

in site settings->navigation i created new link and assign a SharePoint group to be the audiences of this link

when login by user from this group(audiences) the link appears on both top navigation bar and navigation bar beside "my site " in the top of the page ,[note that this last navigation bar exist in "mysite.master"]

when login by user outside this group the link disappear only from top navigation bar but it still exist in "my site " navigation bar

can any one help me to find why the link appear in "my site" navigation bar when log in by user not in audience group

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are on the right way. I think it should work. I've created so many links and assigned permission to them using audience targeting.

It should work. Please Re-start your server and try again.

Comment: when i add page two links appears, one beside "my site" and other in top navigation bar, when log in as user not audience , the link hide fom top navigation bar but still exist beside "my site"

Comment: are you sure it disapeared in both navigation bar?

Comment: I've worked with left navigation Menu and i'm sure, It will work. Please Edit your Link again and select a SharePoint Group as audience.

Comment: i know that it will disappear from left navigation but it still appear beside "my site", if the links disappear from the top left page beside "my site" please tell me precisely the steps and permissions that you grant to user and group

Comment: please note that there is two navigation bar in the top of the page    first is top navigation bar , second is navigation bar of "may site" ,the problem in the second navigation bar"my site"

Comment: the navigation bar of "my site" exist in master page "mysite.master"

Comment: I've found it. Go through Site Setting -> Site Collection Administration -> Site collection navigation-> Enable audience targeting.    Then set your audience to the corresponding links

Comment: You also have to enable publishing feature from site setting->site Action-> manage site features

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23967/discussion-between-forhad-hossain-and-mahamed-wasim)